# How to replace the text-content of an html-markup's first tag with the help of either iQuery or plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, replace, markup

I have an array of markup-strings like e.g.

```
const array = [
  '<p class="item">text</p>',
  '<h1>hello</h1>',
];
```

I want to replace the text-content of each markup-string's first tag. I thought of using the `replace` method but since it's not always a `<p>` tag and sometimes a tag's markup features a class-attribute, I can't rely on just targeting the text between `<p>` and `</p>`. I tried to use jQuery's `html` method but it's not working.

How could one achieve the just described task?

Comment: Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing any kind of markup should not be left to regex based approaches, due to the latter by design can not compete with a specialized parser.

Thus said, the OP might have a look into [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) (for parsing) as well as into [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) (text replacement) and [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) (serializing again).

```js
function replaceContentOfFirstTagInMarkup(markup, content) {
  const targetNode = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(markup ?? '', "text/html")
    ?.body
    ?.firstElementChild ?? null;

  if (targetNode !== null) {

    targetNode.innerText = content ?? '';
    markup = targetNode.outerHTML;
  }
  return markup;
}

const markupList = [
  '<p class="item">text</p>',
  '<h1>hello</h1>',
];
const contentReplacementList = [
  'the quick brown fox',
  'Hello world',
];

const newMarkupList = markupList
  .map((markup, idx) =>
    replaceContentOfFirstTagInMarkup(
      markup, contentReplacementList[idx]
    )
  );
console.log({
  markupList,
  contentReplacementList,
  newMarkupList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A possible jQuery based implementation could look like that.

```js
const markupList = [
  '<p class="item">text</p>',
  '<h1>hello</h1>',
];
const contentReplacementList = [
  'the quick brown fox',
  'Hello world',
];

const newMarkupList = [];

$(markupList)
  .each((idx, markup) => newMarkupList
    .push(
      $(markup)
        .empty()
        .text(contentReplacementList[idx])
        [0]
        .outerHTML
    )
  );
console.log({
  markupList,
  contentReplacementList,
  newMarkupList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```